# Why is my account blocked again?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

My account was freed from blocked , and I recently asked a question and got positive votes, but my account went blocked again.

Comment: By recently I presume you mean [this](http://superuser.com/questions/1130441/windows-10-stuck-in-reboot-loop) question, if so it has a single postive vote.  You only have 6 questions people can vote on currently, your total score of those 6 questions, that isn't good.  Your 0 score is before you take into the score of those 6 questions that were deleted by the community.  If more of your questions were deleted, since you last asked about your question ban, then you are even in a worst position.  Deleted questions can't be improved or voted on.

Comment: @Ramhound there's another 6 questions which are deleted

Comment: @Sathya - I know that.  I was just counting the 6 deleted questions from the last time they asked.

Answer (score 4):

[This link to Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) pretty much covers all we can tell you. It includes the reasons why the automatic bans happen; how to get unbanned; etc.

There's nothing a moderator or other users can do to directly help you with an automatic ban, and it looks like your account *isn't* manually suspended by a moderator, so you just need to improve the existing questions/answers you have to get unblocked.

BTW, deleting your questions/answers does not help. That actually makes it *more* likely that you will be question/answer banned, especially if you're in a "marginal" situation like yours.

Comment: 0 total score between 6 questions, a single question with -3 score, and numerous deleted questions with even worst scores then that single account isn't a case of being marginal.  The author has recieved a single postive vote since May 2016.